# Verification of Green's Theorem in a Simple Case

Tags: proof-verification, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

> Show that Green's Theorem is satisfied for $\vec{G}: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ $\vec{G}=y\vec{i}-x\vec{j}$ and the path $C: x=\sin t, y=\cos t$ for $0\leq t \leq 2\pi$.

We want to show $$\oint_{\partial C} (Pdx+Qdy)=\iint_C \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\,dx\,dy$$

LHS is
\begin{align}
\oint_{\partial C} (ydx-xdy)&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t) dt\\
& = 2\pi\\
\end{align}

RHS is
\begin{align}
\iint_C \ 2 \,dx\,dy&=2\pi\\
\end{align}

Is this correct working/logic?

Edit: where $P=y$ and $Q=-x$.

Comment: Maybe you should point out what $P$ and $Q$ are.

Comment: Yes, that's my bad. Question has been edited.